# Lifecycle of Application instance (regarding services and activities)

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

If my Android app has a running service (e.g. extending a [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService)) does the service always has access to the exact same `Application` instance (by using the `getApplication` method) as every (maybe later started) `Activity` of my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application` instance is a singleton. It is created when Android starts any component of your application in a new process.

Note that if Android kills the process hosting your application and then restarts your `Service`, it will run in a new process and Android will create a new instance of the `Application` class.

Comment: And I guess all activities started after creating the new process will use the newly create `Application` instance then.

Comment: Yes, all components (`Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Provider`) within the process will use the same `Application` instance.

Answer (score -2):

yes your service will always have access to same application instance,
if your activity is restarted then it will have create another instance

Comment: What do you mean by "create another instance"? Then both (service and activity) won't have access to the same instance?! They would only share the same instance if the restarted activity would somehow reuse the instance of the service (assuming the service runs longer than every activity).